# 'undefined' getting appended to a specific Web API call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

'Undefined' is getting appended to a specific WebAPI call in my angular application where as other calls succeed without issue.

Both registerUser and login call fails because of 'Undefined' character:

Request URL: http://localhost:25971/undefined/api/Account/Register

Request URL: http://localhost:25971/undefined/Token

Here is my code:

```
    (function () {
    "use strict";
    angular
        .module("userManagement")
        .controller("mainCtrl", ["userAccount", mainCtrl])

    function mainCtrl(userAccount) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.isLoggedIn = false;
        vm.message = '';
        vm.userData = {
            userName: '',
            email: '',
            password: '',
            confirmPassword: ''
        };

        vm.registerUser = function () {
            vm.userData.confirmPassword = vm.userData.password;
            userAccount.registration.registerUser(vm.userData, function (data) {
                vm.confirmPassword = "";
                vm.message = "...Registration successful";
                // vm.login();
            });
        }
        vm.login = function () {
            vm.userData.grant_type = "password";
            vm.userData.userName = vm.userData.email;
            userAccount.login.loginUser(vm.userData, function (data) {
                vm.isLoggedIn = true;
                vm.password = "";
                vm.message = "";
                vm.token = data.access_token;
            });
        }
    }
}());
```

Here is the code in userAccount factory method:

```
 (function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("common.services")
    .factory("userAccount", ["$resource", "appsettings", userAccount])
    function userAccount($resource, appsettings) {
        return {
            registration: $resource(appsettings.serverPath + "/api/Account/Register", null,
                {
                    'registerUser': { method: 'POST' }
                }),
            login: $resource(appsettings.serverPath + "/Token", null,
                {
                    'loginUser': {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                        transformRequest: function (data, headersGetter) {
                        var str = [];
                        for (var d in data) {
                            str.push(encodeURIComponent(d) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[d]));
                            return str.join("&")
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }

})();
```

Appsettings is defined like this:

```
(function () {
   "use strict";
    angular.module("common.services", ["ngResource"]).constant("appsettings", {
        serverpath:"http://localhost:25879/"
    });
}());
```

I am new to Angular and WebAPI, any help or direction to find the issue would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you show us your `appsettings` as well?

Comment: appsettings.serverPath not set for those calls. please check consol log

Comment: (function () {
   // "use strict";
    angular.module("common.services", ["ngResource"]).constant("appsettings", {
        serverpath:"http://localhost:25879/"
    });
}());

Comment: @MujeebuRahman No error on console log, have updated the question with appsettings code.

Comment: appsettings.serverPath replace as appsettings.serverpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `appsettings` constant should look like:

```
(function (angular) {
   "use strict";
    angular.module("common.services", ["ngResource"]).constant("appsettings", {
        serverPath: "http://localhost:25879"
    });
}(angular));
```

The property `serverpath` is not the same as `serverPath` and in you case `serverPath` is `undefined`. You should respect the casing.

Comment: Feels so dumb! :|

Answer (score 1):

Check for `serverPath` in `apiSettings`

Comment: I have updated the question with app settings file. Is there anything specific I should check for?

Comment: Typo error. serverpath is not equal to serverPath. Check the casing